# What is the browser feature called that ES6 Promises use?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I was recently asked and did not know the answer; "What is the feature that all modern browsers support that allow the use of Promises"?

Please correct me here if I'm wrong, but my understanding was that in recent years, XMLHttpRequest was used in Javascript and was what jQuery used behind the scenes for $.ajax until version 3 where jQuery now uses promises.

I thought Promises were apart of ES6/Javascript2015, therefore I thought it was Javascript that dealt with Promises and not a browser feature as such.

Comment: Promises have been "around" since well before ES2015 - so, there is no *browser feature*, whatever that is

Comment: `Promises` do not replace `XMLHttpRequest` - jQuery still uses `XMLHttpRequest`, and has returned a Promise (well, close enough) since an early 2.x, or maybe a later 1.x version - Promises in jQuery are not new

Comment: Callbacks. . . .

Comment: Maybe morality, otherwise they would not care about their promises :P The question is poorly phrased - it could be callbacks, asynchronicity, proxies? but except the last one they are around in JS since ages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe they meant [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which is based on promises.